# background-image repeat as 180deg rotated image

Tags: css

I've problem with rotate background-image. For example: I'd like to use background-image which   first part is white and second part is black. I need to rotate repeating image so that the next image was inverted.

Comment: can you please explain the issue, the desired behaviour and post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this with CSS3. What you could do, is make one image of the standard image and the 180° rotated image next to each other, and repeat that.